# Application Installed Not Found in Android Folder?

Tags: applications, 4.4-kitkat, installation

I am not sure if i am missing something here, what i did was i installed an application and i want to batch some files inside the installed application folder. Usually all applications  installed are in the Android folder but the application i installed is not there, i even tried to see the size of the folder before and after installation and no difference.

The application installed create a shortcut and when i run it, it asks to download some data from the INTERNET, that is the nature of the application i am trying to locate.

Can anybody tell me if there is any other folder i should be looking in ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the application. In case of applications downloading additional data, some applications create their own folder on the SD card, or they to their appropriate folder in the Android folder on the SD card (either in *data* or *obb*), or even somewhere else. Application itself (without the additional data) should normally be stored on the /data partition.

Comment: Is there a way to now where is an app is installed ?

Comment: Well, first you'll need to see what the actual name of the application is. To do this, find the app under Application menu in Settings app. Look for the name under the usual name shown (it's `com.google.android.calendar` for calendar app, for example). After finding out, try to search the system by that name, by either using searching engine of the file manager, or doing it manually, by looking in /data/app, /sdcard/Android (look in both internal and external SD card).